# Window Subclassing terminates the external application

Tags: dll, window, code-injection, subclassing

I am trying to subclass the menu of an external application. I am using the SetWindowLong function to subclass the Windows Procedure, it works well, but after doing what I want, it terminates the application, I dont know why.

This is the function I inject:

```
DWORD __stdcall AddNewMenuItem(){

  HWND hwndAna = NULL;
  HMENU hMenu = NULL;

  hwndAna = FindWindowA("NameOfTheMainWindow,NULL);


  if(hwndAna != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
    hMenu = GetMenu(hwndAna);

     if(hMenu != NULL){

    HMENU hMenuFile = CreatePopupMenu();
    AppendMenu(hMenuFile, MF_STRING , (UINT_PTR)ID_Load , L"Show Info");
    AppendMenu(hMenuFile, MF_STRING , (UINT_PTR)ID_VWS , L"Go to Site");
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hMenuFile, L"Site");

    DrawMenuBar(hwndAna);
    OriginalProcedure = SetWindowLongA(hwndAna, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)MyProc);
      return 1;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And this is the My own Windows Procedure:

```
LRESULT APIENTRY MyProc(HWND hwnd, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
  switch(iMsg)
  {
     case WM_COMMAND:
         switch LOWORD(wParam)
         {
            case ID_Load:

            MessageBoxA(NULL,"this is info", "Information!", MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            break;  

            case ID_VWS:
            ShellExecute(NULL, L"Open", L"http://www.gotowebsite.com/", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
            break;

            }
    break;
   }

    return CallWindowProc((WNDPROC)OriginalProcedure, hwnd, iMsg, wParam, lParam);  

}
```

And these are the IDs:

```
#define ID_VWS 0x8801
#define ID_Load 0x8802
```

All codes react to the messages, I mean it appends menu successfully, when I click the submenus it shows messagebox etc, but after this, it terminates the application. Somehow it returns WM_CLOSE message after ID messages and I cant manage it. I appreciate your help.